# Exception in setInterval callback

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting this error after calling a callback function like so:

```
function callbackInterval(test) {
   Meteor._debug("Test");
}
Meteor.setInterval(callbackInterval(test), 60000);
```

This is the error output

```
Exception in setInterval callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
at packages/meteor/timers.js:6
at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `setInterval` a function reference (name or anonymous function), not call the function.

You want:

```
function callbackInterval(test) {
   Meteor._debug("Test");
}

Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    callbackInterval(test)
}, 60000);
```

If you didn't need to pass `callbackInterval` a parameter, you would then be able to call:

```
Meteor.setInterval(callbackInterval, 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If still needing, or for those who needs it, the correct way would be:

```
function callbackInterval(test) {
  Meteor._debug("Test");
}
Meteor.setInterval(callbackInterval, 60000);
```

as the test parameter would be injected on the function, but i don't know if set Interval would receive a parameter...

Answer (score 0):

You can't set function with parameter as a callback function. Use an anonymous function like this instead:

```
var callback = function ()  {
   callbackInterval(test)
   Meteor._debug("Test");
}
Meteor.setInterval(callbackInterval, 60000);
```

Comment: FYI, what you're using is not an anonymous function.  An anonymous function is not required for `setInterval()1.  What is required is passing a function reference instead of actually calling the function and passing the return value which is the difference between what you are doing and what the OP is doing.  So, correct code, but wrong explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the parameter to the call back function

You can call the callback function with Parameter like this

```
setInterval(function (){
        callbackInterval(test)
 }, 1000);
```