# Why does calling a method using Meteor.setInterval throw a TypeError exception?

Tags: javascript, meteor, setinterval

I am trying to use the `Meteor.setInterval` function but I have some troubles using it.

Here is my code :

```
Meteor.methods({
  init : function(){
    console.log('test');
  },
  start : function(period){
    console.log('start : period '+period);

    Meteor.setInterval(Meteor.call('init'),period);
  }
});

Meteor.call('start', 100);
```

I see "test" in my console 1 time, then I get the following error :

> Exception in setInterval callback: TypeError : undefined is not a function.

I've been looking at this question : [Exception in setInterval callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007264/exception-in-setinterval-callback) but I did it in a different way (using `Method.methods`).

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
Meteor.setInterval(Meteor.call('init'),period);
```

Now try to think about what the engine does. First, `Meteor.setInterval`. What he needs for this function is:

- A callback
- A number of milliseconds

What do you pass? The number of milliseconds, and for a callback you pass `Meteor.call('init')`. The engine sees your `call`, and executes it because that's what you ask him to do with the parenthesis. And your call returns nothing. And then the `setInterval` tries to execute nothing.

So, how can you pass a function with parameters to `Meteor.setInterval`? One way is to wrap it inside a closure:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
  Meteor.call('init'); 
}, period });
```

This way, your `call` is **not** immediately executed, it's only executed when the `setInterval` uses the callback, which then executes your `call`.

You can also partially apply the `call`. There is two ways:

1. Native :

   ```
   Meteor.setInterval(Meteor.call.bind(null, 'init'), period);
   ```
2. With [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) :

   ```
   Meteor.setInterval(_.partial(Meteor.call, 'init'), period);
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the good explaination, it works perfectly now :)